# Напишите программу, которая в каждом слове заданного предложения меняет местами первую и последнюю буквы. (python)

Tags: python

друзья, помогите, не пойму как можно сделать. Например: Солнце светит ярко и птицы поют. 
Чтобы вышло так:
еолнцС тветис оркя и ытицп тоюп

Comment: Приведите пример предложения, пожалуйста. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit]. Решить задачу будет непросто, если в предложении сложная пунктуация.

Comment: Получить первый символ можно с помощью `word[0]`, последний — `word[-1]`. Сложность в делении предложения на слова. В простейшем случае можно делить по пробелам: `s.split()`.

Comment: можете, пожалуйста показать пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
s = 'Солнце светит ярко и птицы поют'

words = s.split()  # ['Солнце', 'светит', 'ярко', 'и', 'птицы', 'поют']
result = []
for word in words:
    if len(word) < 2:
        result.append(word)
        continue
    new_word = word[-1] + word[1:-1] + word[0]
    result.append(new_word)

print(' '.join(result))
```

***stdout:***

```py
еолнцС тветис оркя и ытицп тоюп
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!